# On yarn2 can I share dependencies or devDependencies between the root package.json and a child repo?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, yarn-v2

I am using yarn2 workspaces.

Let's say I have a folder structure like this:

```
root/
- package.json
- repo-a/
-- package.json
- repo-b/
-- package.json
```

Both repo are using `eslint` for example.
Is it possible to only have `eslint` package in the root package.json? Or do I have to install it on all child repos ?

Thanks,